# Delete all visible sheets but a specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with below code.

I want to delete all visible sheets but a certain sheet, when a user closes the workbook.
This is the code:

```
Private Sub workbook_BeforeClose(cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Workbook
    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        If ws.Name <> "Choose BU" Then ws.Delete
    End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

It says "Object required", however I thought the worksheet per default is an object in VBA?

Comment: `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`

Comment: Type `Option Explicit` on top of your code...

Comment: My god, of course… Brain fart, thanks.

Comment: Or slightly shorter `For Each ws in Me.Worksheets`, since this is in the `ThisWorkbook` module.

Comment: If you want to delete after specific sheet, you'd have to get first the index of each sheet and then compare it to the one you'll like to remain

Comment: Your code will delete all sheets but "Choose BU" and not after "Choose BU", won't it.

Comment: Yes, but that is also what I need. It's a reset function for the next user. Thanks for helping out guys!

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        With ws

            If .Visible = True And .Name <> "Choose BU" Then
                .Delete
            End If

        End With

    Next ws

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```